# Where is ingested data "stored" when ingesting for text chunking/embedding generation for a RAG implementation?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, large-language-model

I've been researching all over about this - I am building a RAG chatbot app using ingested data to query for document Q&A.

I am struggling with having the data available for my LLM to ask; while developing locally I ingest it either in the same file as where embedding + vector storage is done, or if possible not all together, but do I lose my data then?

What "exists" when I am developing locally and when? I can ingest and load documents, then chunk them, then embed + vector store, then question asking. I doubt this all should go in the same .py file. How does it work, then?

I've tried ingestion with both separated file/modules and all in one .py script. Results are usually "no data available to answer this question" but I can print out the ingested documents' text in the command line. I have also tried both online and local LLM options, like Google Gemini and Ollama's local models.

To clarify - if I run a Python script that loads documents only, would runtime memory include this data if I import my documents variable from the first into a split/chunk process in another Python script? If not, I could have the first script call the functions in the second, but I'm back to all one file again, really.

Tech stack details:

- Python 12
- LangChain tools including Supabase integration
- Supabase vector store w/ postgreSQL database
- Streamlit for UI
- tried but not set on using: Vecs (library for postgreSQL vector storage), different LLMs (not set on Gemini), various LlamaIndex options